# How can I hide the index.php file for yii in apache/.htaccess/mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I have this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
#if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And I'm using Yii 1.1.15 (**this site was taken from 1.1.13** version but such version is not available anymore for download, so I'm using it in a 1.1.15 framework install - althought it has no problem as far as I can see), having a conf/main.php file like:

```
<?php

return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(dirname(__FILE__)),
    'name'=>'Grand Duval - Códigos premiados',
    'defaultController'=>'participantes/create',
    'language'=>'es',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'mypassword',
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1', '::1'),
        ),
    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),

        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'sbuser',
            'password' => 'dbpassword',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

The important part here is:

```
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

Such config is intended - and does work like that - to generate absolute urls like `http://www.mydomain.dev/controller/action` for controller `controller` and action `action`.

I have the problem with the `.htaccess` file: If I try to hit `http://www.mydomain.dev/controller/action`, the url is not found. However if I hit `http://www.mydomain.dev/index.php/controller/action` it is found. It looks that `.htacccess` has no effect at all (It is the exact same if I delete the .htaccess file).

**Q**: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. **After ensuring that mod_rewrite was active for my other sites** I asked myself: Is my .htaccess being recognized?

So i wanted to force a 500 error by corrupting my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
TryToForceA500
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And no error was triggered! So I asked myself -again-: Why isn't it being recognized? and **checked my  site .conf file** and found:

```
AllowOverride none
```

And changed to:

```
AllowOverride all
```

(this is just a dev server, so that setup is fine for me)

And then the file was recognized and worked!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to enable mod_rewrite try:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Then just restart your server.

Comment: No, it is enabled. Otherwise i'd get a 500 error. BTW I tried that command right now, and neither worked

Comment: Althought the answer you wrote was not the answer to my problem (I found it), it is a common problem people finds and I found some time ago. Ensuring mod_rewrite is active is not trivial in apache (althought it is trivial for its 'cousin' in nginx) and most of the times it is the solution. upvote :).