# how to hide index.php from my url in yii framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

my code runs with url:

```
http://localhost/yii/index.php/Adminlogin
```

I want url to look like:

```
http://localhost/yii/Adminlogin
```

.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            'redirect/<redirectUrl>'=>'site/index',
            'login'=>'site/login',
            'privacy'=>'site/privacy',
            'password'=>'site/forgot',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hide the index.php file for yii in apache/.htaccess/mod\_rewrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061591/how-can-i-hide-the-index-php-file-for-yii-in-apache-htaccess-mod-rewrite)

Comment: you can refer this Documentation URL for your reference : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/yii/6143/setting-in-your-main-php-file#t=201610270410382135132

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` instead of `RewriteRule . index.php`

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your main.php

```
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,
```

And in your htaccess use below,

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, ... remember to `AllowOverride` in your main apache configuration:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/yii.sample/web/">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Is it possible that your `web/.htaccess` is correct, but your apache never allowed your

Answer (score 0):

my htaccess would look like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```